Importing sympy leads to a recursion error
I am running Python 3.12.7 built from source on a Raspberry Pi 5 8GB Model B Rev 1.0 (default 64-bit Raspbian based on Debian 12/bookworm).
When importing sympy (literally import sympy), I get the following error:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation

The line that causes the recursions seems to be this one:
from sympy.polys.numberfields.resolvent_lookup import resolvent_coeff_lambdas

located at ~/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields/galois_resolvents.py, line 28.
Running only this line causes this traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sympy.polys.numberfields.resolvent_lookup import resolvent_coeff_lambdas
  File "/home/danrybir/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sympy/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from .polys import (Poly, PurePoly, poly_from_expr, parallel_poly_from_expr,
  File "/home/danrybir/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sympy/polys/__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
    from .numberfields import (minpoly, minimal_polynomial, primitive_element,
  File "/home/danrybir/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .galoisgroups import galois_group
  File "/home/danrybir/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields/galoisgroups.py", line 24, in <module>
    from sympy.polys.numberfields.galois_resolvents import (
  File "/home/danrybir/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sympy/polys/numberfields/galois_resolvents.py", line 28, in <module>
    from sympy.polys.numberfields.resolvent_lookup import resolvent_coeff_lambdas
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation

Is there some way to fix this?
What I am really trying to do is trying to initialize the Adam optimizer in PyTorch, which imports sympy.

What version of SymPy do you have?

and how did you install both Python and SymPy?

See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/26692  The problem should be solved with Sympy 1.13

My SymPy version was 1.12. Updating it helped resolving the issue. Thanks!
